# how to send value in SIGNAL

Tags: qt, qt5

I am passing a `QVBoxLayout` as an argument to a method and creating controls at runtime.

```
QDoubleSpinBox *test; // Global variable at the top of the cpp file

 void Sph::CreateUI(QVBoxLayout* layout)
 {
  QDoubleSpinBox *PositionXSpinBox = new QDoubleSpinBox;
  test = PositionXSpinBox;
  PositionXSpinBox->setRange(-10000, 10000);
  PositionXSpinBox->setSingleStep(1.0);
  PositionXSpinBox->setValue(40);
  layout->addWidget(PositionXSpinBox);
  bool ok = QObject::connect(PositionXSpinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), 
                             this, SLOT( ParamChange()));
}
```

In  my current scenario I am declaring global varibles at the top of the .cpp file, for example in this case `QDoubleSpinBox *test;`
and in the `ParamChanged` function I am changing a private variable of the class .

```
void Sph::ParamChange()
{
  this->fSegments = test->value();
  this->isChanged = true;
}
```

1) is it possible to send the value of PositionXSpinBox in the connect signal itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if you asking this simple thing, but yes, slot can receive the parameter of the signal. Signal parameters wouldn't make much sense otherwise, now would they?

Something like this

```
void Sph::ParamChange(double value)
{
  this->fSegments = value;
  this->isChanged = true;
}
```

and this

```
bool ok = QObject::connect(PositionXSpinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), 
                           this, SLOT( ParamChange(double)));
```

The more modern way to do this connect would be to use the new syntax:

```
QObject::connect(PositionXSpinBox, &QSpinBox::valueChanged,
                 this, &Sph::ParamChange);
```

This is preferable because it will give compile time error if you for example make a typo in method names.

---

As a side note, if this indeed was your problem, I highly recommend going through the Qt basics, for example this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: It is better to use this syntax with function pointers: `bool ok = QObject::connect(PositionXSpinBox, &QSpinBox::valueChanged), this, &Sph::ParamChange));` This way you get compile time errors instead of runtime errors if the signal fails to connect.

Comment: @RickPat True, I'll augment the answer